# How to programatically set the width of an Android EditText view in DPs (not pixels)

Tags: android

I'm dynamically generating a grid of EditText views in code based on a specified number of rows and columns.  I want each of the EditText views to be the same width (e.g., 100dp).

Although I can set the size of the views with either setWidth or by creating a LayoutParam object, I only seem able to specify the value in pixels.  I instead want to use the DP (density independent) units, similar to what I've done using an XML layout.

How can this be done in code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a method in a Utils class that does this conversion:

```
public static int dip(Context context, int pixels) {
   float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
   return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Now that your talking about your Utils class, that seems like a great place to put a lot of methods, and functions that are to be used by your main program or other classes, kind of like a global place to put things that are used many times by your program?

Comment: Thanks guys for the code.  I'll add a conversion function to my application's Utils class.  I'm new to Android. I can't help wondering why the setWidth method doesn't have the same built-in flexibility as setting the android:layout_width attribute in an XML layout.

Comment: can i use this method to set the width of an XML control in the corresponding activity class? I notice the first param is Context, can you given an example of how this helper method can be used to set dynamic with onCreate of an activity? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
float value = 12;
int unit = TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP;
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dipPixel = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, value, metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the below code i was  able to do it.**

> int width = (int)
>   TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (100)your Size
>   in int, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());